# I don't get band structure of solids

Tags: quantum-mechanics, solid-state-physics, discrete

If the energy levels of bound electrons are discrete, why do band structures in solids arise?

Comment: Here's a simulation for [band structure.](http://phet.colorado.edu/en/simulation/band-structure) It could help some.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could think of making a solid by slowly bringing all the atoms closer together.  As they get closer the discrete electron orbits start to bump into each other.  But the electrons can't be in the same state, and you start to get new states that are a combination of the discrete states.. And these form bands.(Yeah that last is a bit of a cop out, see a solid state text.)  Note: you have bands in insulators where the electrons are not free.

Weird, what I'm pretty sure is the right answer gets voted to the bottom.  If I edit this will it get bumped up to the front of the line again?  So putting atoms in a periodic array does not guarantee that bands will form.  When atoms get close to each other the electrons are forced into bands because they are fermions and can't be in the same state.

Comment: I think this is misleading, since bands arise from the periodic potential even for a single particle, they have nothing to do with the fermionic nature of electrons.

Comment: Hi @fqq,  Well you get bands in things like glasses too, where there is no periodic potential.  I don't think the periodic potentials make the bands, it does make it easier to solve.  The wavefunction overlap is used in the tight binding method for calculating band structure.  (Do you have a copy of Ashcroft and Mermin?)  Check out fig 10.4.  For widely separated atoms (in a periodic potential) you get N-fold degenerate levels, as you shrink the lattice, bands form.  (Because electrons are fermions, IMHO)

Comment: The bands here are derived in a single-particle setting. I don't know anything about glasses, so I can't discuss how they emerge there.

Comment: Indeed I will agree with @GeorgeHerold - overlap of states leads to degeneracy splitting, leading to band formation. This occurs whether the potential is periodic or not.  A periodic potential leads to a calculable situation, but is not a requirement for band formation. See glasses, degenerate doping in semiconductors, etc.  I too would suggest a close look at Ashcroft & Mermin, or the first chapter in Pankove's "Optical Processes in Semiconductors."

Comment: @JonCuster, Oh thankyou!  (I was starting to lose hope.)  Just to reiterate.  The tight binding method (also call LCAO, linear combination of atomic orbitals) uses the atomic wavefunctions as the basis set.  I'm not a theorist, but just like the Bloch functions the atomic wavefunctions also form a complete set and can be used as a starting point for a calculation of the band structure.  With the Bloch functions the bands drop out easier.  So that's what people tend to teach.

Comment: @GeorgeHerold, I guess I'd phrase it a bit differently.  Solid state physics courses often focus on crystals because they are important in many fields, but also because the periodicity allows you to construct solvable equations. What is missing is the reminder to the students that periodic potentials aren't required to occur in a solid (with amorphous silicon and glasses being obvious examples).

Comment: Totally agree with you @JonCuster,  picking the right basis set makes life so much easier.  I certainly don't want to calculate anything with LCAO.  I only mentioned it, because it gave a model for going from atomic states to bands, which was the original question.

Comment: @GeorgeHerold I downvoted this answer a few days ago, for I held the same opinion as fqq expressed. I always thought bands by definition are functions of bloch momentum, so how can it be defined for nonperiodic system? I'd be happy to remove my downvote if it is clarified.

Comment: @JiaYiyang I don't know.  You might expect the band edge in glasses and amorphous solids to be less well defined.  Here's one paper that talks some about it.   http://www.bzu.edu.pk/jrscience/vol15no3/3.pdf  (I googled "calculation of band structure in glasses")

Comment: Ok, I kinda what was going on. In fact OP's question can be interpreted in two ways, the first is "if energy levels of each individual atom are discrete, how come when atoms come together and form solid, they become continuous", to which your answer is the correct one. The second is "electron in the atom is bounded, hence the energy levels are discrete; now electron in solids is also bounded(by solid), then why aren't the energy levels discrete?", to which the answers saying "electron in solids is not really bounded, since we treat solid as infinite in extent" are correct.

Comment: But it seems my vote is locked since I voted too long ago, sorry for that.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I am by no means and expert on solid state but I might be a little helpful.

Band structure in solids arises due only to periodicity of the lattice. It all comes down to this periodicity.

Periodicity of the lattice makes the potential also periodic.

This periodicity has many (interesting) consequences (Bloch states and bla bla bla) but the one that matters to you is that energy eigenstates of the Hamiltonian are specified by $\vec{k}$, a vector of the reciprocal space, and another index that I will call "n" (this "n" will label the bands).

Now, the reciprocal is periodic becuase the crystal is periodic. Then

$\epsilon_n(\vec{k})=\epsilon_n(\vec{k}+period)$

So you see that this energy spectrum of the single electron in the periodic potential of the crystal has to be bounded and all energy values for a given $n$ must be in a band of possible values. THIS is the band structure. You have a band for every "n".

Now, are all $\epsilon_n(\vec{k})$ allowed? No, (at least no if you work under [Born and Von Karman Boundary conditions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Born%E2%80%93von_Karman_boundary_condition)( which is what I have always seen done)). This boundary conditions discretize the posible $\vec{k}$ vectors (and actually you can limit yoursef to the $\vec{k}$ of a primitive cell of the reciprocal lattice because of Born and Von Karman).

So you see, electrons in crystals are also in a discrete spectrum.

This is quite nicely explained in Ashcroft's book. The idea is, periodicity of the lattice gives you band structure of the energy levels of the single electron. Then Born and Von Karman boundary conditions discretize the spectrum.

Answer (score 1):

When solving for the spectrum, you assume the solid has infinite extent, and so the electron is not really bound. Thus you can get a continuum of momentum.

Consider for example the trivial case where there are no atoms, and you just have a free electron in space. Then the energy is proportional to momentum squared, and momentum can be arbitrarily big, so you just get one big band.

The bands come from the interaction of the electron with the lattice. Suppose we can add in a lattice of atoms with which the electron interacts. How does this change and cause us to have several distinct bands? Well notice the potential from the atoms breaks continuous translational invariance (and therefore momentum conservation). However, since the atoms still lie on a lattice we have invariance under translations by a lattice vectors, and so we have a weaker form of momentum conservation, which says that wavenumber is conserved only up to a wave-vector of the reciprocal lattice to the lattice our atoms are on.

But our energy spectrum still seems connected, how do we get band gaps from non-conservation of momentum? Now consider a reciprocal lattice wave-vector $\vec{K}$ and electron wave number $\vec{k}$ near $\vec{K}/2$. Then symmetries laws do not forbid a transition from wave vector $\vec{k}$ and wavevector $\vec{K}-\vec{k} = \vec{K}/2 + (\vec{K}/2 - \vec{k}) \approx \vec{K}/2\approx \vec{k} $ since $\vec{k} \approx \vec{K}/2$. Now since $\vec{K}-\vec{k} \approx \vec{k}$, the states corresponding to these two wavenumbers have similar $k^2$, i.e., similar unperturbed energy. But now with the lattice in place, there will generically be some matrix element allowing transitions between these states and so these energy levels will split even though they were originally close. Energies near $\dfrac{(\vec{K}/2)^2}{2m}$ therefore are not attained because of this splitting and so there is a gap in the spectrum. This is the band gap.

Answer (score 0):

Because in solid states, the electrons are not bound.

A simple derivation of the continuous bands can be made if you look at particle in a box ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_potential_well)).

If we approach the number of an infinite box with infinite particles (and constant density), there are infinite states, and the states get closer, as the energy gap goes as $L^{-2}$.

Therefore a continuous band arises.

The derivation of the band gaps is a bit more complicated.
In the simple one dimensional case, this is related to the periodicity of the atoms. Looking at the wavelength, that is the same as the periodicity of the crystal, there are basically two options: the one where the electrons have a high density probability at the atoms, therefore they have a lower energy, as the are attracted. The other possibility is that they have a higher probability between the atoms. This is energetically not so good for them. So we see we have 2 states with the same $k$-vector, but with different energies. This is the reason for the band-gap.

Comment: *"Because in solid states, the electrons are not bound."* Carefully, here. That are not bound to a particular atom, but are (weakly) bound to the solid.